# Can not update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to set up a trigger so that if on an update the 'SyncStatus' is = 1 then the trigger will update the 'SyncStatusTimestamp' = Current_Time_Stamp.

But I amgetting an error saying:

Error:

> Can't update table 'bloodpressurebattery'  in stored function/trigger
>   because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored
>   function/trigger

----------- Table Details -------------

```
CREATE TABLE `bloodpressurebattery` (
    `BloodPressureBatteryID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ByDevSessionId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `ByPatientId` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ByDeviceId` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Value` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `SequenceId` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `SyncStatus` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Timestamp` TIMESTAMP(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `WrittenToAndroidDatabaseTimestamp` TIMESTAMP(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `WrittenToServerDatabaseTimestamp6` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `SyncStatusTimestamp` TIMESTAMP(3) NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000',
    PRIMARY KEY (`BloodPressureBatteryID`),
    INDEX `ByDevSessionId` (`ByDevSessionId`),
    CONSTRAINT `bloodpressurebattery_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ByDevSessionId`) REFERENCES `devicesession` (`DeviceSessionID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=524874
;
```

---- Trigger Details ----------------------

```
DELIMITER //

    CREATE TRIGGER SyncStatusTimestamp_bloodpressurebattery_after_update
    AFTER UPDATE
       ON bloodpressurebattery FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN

    DECLARE _SyncStatusTimestamp INT ; 
    DECLARE _BloodPressureBatteryID INT  ;


     SET _BloodPressureBatteryID = (SELECT bloodpressurebattery.BloodPressureBatteryID As _BloodPressureBatteryID
                    FROM  bloodpressurebattery                     
                    WHERE BloodPressureBatteryID =  new.BloodPressureBatteryID  AND SyncStatus = 1);                                            

      IF _BloodPressureBatteryID > 0 THEN

       UPDATE bloodpressurebattery SET SyncStatusTimestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  AND bloodpressurebattery.BloodPressureBatteryID = _BloodPressureBatteryID ;

      END IF  ;

     END
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error cause Recursive trigger are not supported in MySQL. You have rigger defined on `bloodpressurebattery` table and on `UPDATE` you are again trying to access the same table by means of below DML statement

```
UPDATE bloodpressurebattery SET SyncStatusTimestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  .....
```

Per [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)

> Stored functions cannot be used recursively.
>
> • Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.